# Write a formula where the resulting answer is the same row but a different column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I am trying to create a formula such that if `B1` is equal to a range of rows in column `C`, then a1 is equal to the corresponding row in column `D`.

So, for example, if `B1` is equal to `C14`, then `A1` is `D14`, but if it’s equal to `C9`, then `D9`.

I have started an `IFS` formula like this...  `=IFS(b1<>"","",b1=c1,d1,b1=c2,d2...` This would be fine, but I have 500 rows of data, so the formula will be insanely long. I’m hoping there’s an easier way.

Any help would be great

Comment: *for example, if B1 is equal to C14, then A1 is D14, but if it’s equal to C9, then D9.* It is common VLOOKUP() descrription.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for `VLOOKUP`.
In this case you want the formula in A1 to be `=VLOOKUP(B1,$C:$D,2,FALSE)`.